# noalign in tabularx

Tags: tables, tabularx

```
\begin{table}[H]
\center
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| l | X |}
    \hline
    \textbf{Daten} & \textbf{XXX}
    \hline
    \textit{Crawler} & 
        \begin{itemize}
            \item task
            \item crawl
        \end{itemize} \\
    \textit{Disk} & 
        \begin{itemize}
            \item flash
        \end{itemize} \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption
[test2]
{test1}
\label{tab:test}
\end{table}
```

This gives methe following error: ! Misplaced \noalign.
\hline ->\noalign

Can someone help me please? I am kinda new to LaTeX

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Try a `\\ `  right after `\textbf{XXX}`. If that doesn't help please add the essential information to make your code a MWE (minimal yet containing documentclass and needed packages).

Comment: unrelated to the error but also `\center` is not a latex command (it is the internal definition of `\begin{center}`) use `\centering`.

Comment: Sometimes it helps masking the itemize environment in something like a parbox.

Answer (score 1):

you miss one `\\` ... (as mentioned in above comments).

off-topics: see if the following changes (based on added packages) is interesting to you:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem} % added
\usepackage{etoolbox} % added
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{%
         \setlist[itemize]{ nosep,     % <-- new list setup
                            topsep     = 0pt,
                            partopsep  = 0pt,
                            leftmargin = *,
                            before     = \vspace{-0.6\baselineskip},
                            after      = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
                            }}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf, textfont=bf]{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht] % changed
\centering % changed/corrected
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| l | X |}
\hline
\textbf{Daten} & \textbf{XXX}       \\ % <--- missing \\
\hline
\textit{Crawler} &
    \begin{itemize}
        \item task
        \item crawl
    \end{itemize} \\
\textit{Disk} &
    \begin{itemize}
        \item flash
    \end{itemize} \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption
[test2]
{test1}
\label{tab:test}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

note: caption of tables are usual above table. to achieve this, just move caption before `tabularx`.